# Panel won't open?

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel, listener, jbutton

I am making a pacman game. The plan is to have a GUI that will show the welcome page and a JButton that reads "Play." After the user presses the "Play" button, it will open a new panel that will have an image that will consist of the instructions. On the instructions panel, there will be a JButton that reads "Continue." This will take the user to a GUI with four JButtons reading "Easy," "Medium," "Hard," and "QUIT." The actionPerformed methods for these buttons have already been coded and it works properly (a new JFrame will open with the corresponding Panel to each level, QUIT will quit the program).

The way I created this is that I made a class called GUIPanel and all the panels will open when the GUIPanel object is instantiated.

After I completed the GUI with the levels, that's when I decided to add the Welcome panel and and Instructions panel. So far, I have written code for the Welcome panel. I added it above the code for the level-buttons.

My problem is that whenever I run it, a frame is created but there is no panel. PLEASE HELP ME!! THIS PROJECT IS DUE TOMORROW.

```
//*****************************
//   GUI : Panel
//
//   Updated : May 4th, 2017
//
//*****************************
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;

public class GUIPanel extends JPanel
{
   private Graphics g;
   private BufferedImage buffer;
   public GUIPanel()
   {
      try{
   //welcome panel
      JPanel welcome = new JPanel();
      ImageIcon title = new ImageIcon("welcome.png");
      buffer =  new BufferedImage(200, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
      g = buffer.getGraphics();
      g.drawImage(title.getImage(), 400, 400, 200, 200, null);
   //add button and listener and add onto welcome (JPanel)
      JButton play = new JButton("Play");
      play.addActionListener(new PlayListener());
      welcome.add(play);
      }
      catch(Exception e){
      }
   }

   private class PlayListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
      try{
      JFrame playFrame = new JFrame();
      //creating the panel
         JPanel panel = new JPanel();
         add(panel);
      /*creating the Easy button which will allow the
        user to play the EASY LEVEL of Karelman */
         JButton easyButton = new JButton("Easy");
         easyButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
         easyButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
         easyButton.addActionListener(new EasyListener());
         panel.add(easyButton);
      /*creating the Medium button which will allow the
        user to play the MEDIUM LEVEL of Karelman */
         JButton mediumButton = new JButton("Medium");
         mediumButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
         mediumButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
         mediumButton.addActionListener(new MediumListener());
         panel.add(mediumButton);
      /*creating the random button which will allow the
        user to play the HARD LEVEL of Karelman*/   
         JButton hardButton = new JButton("Hard");
         hardButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
         hardButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
         hardButton.addActionListener(new HardListener());
         hardButton.setBounds(40, 100, 100, 60);
         panel.add(hardButton);
      /*creating the quit button for exiting the program*/
         JButton quitButton = new JButton("QUIT");
         quitButton.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
         quitButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
         quitButton.addActionListener(new QuitListener());
         quitButton.setBounds(150, 300, 25, 25);
         panel.add(quitButton);
         }
         catch(Exception i){
         }
      }
   }

   /*
      EasyListener is attached to the Easy Button
      It will open the Easy Level by creating a
      new frame which will use Easy Ghosts.
   */
   private class EasyListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         try{

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("PLAY KARELMAN -- EASY");
            frame.setSize(708, 738);
            frame.setLocation(350, 0);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);      
            frame.setVisible(true);
         //create panel for Easy Level within frame      
            EasyPanel easy = new EasyPanel();
            frame.setContentPane(easy);
         }
         catch(IOException i){
         }

      }
   }

   /*
      MediumListener is attached to the Medium Button
      It will open the Medium Level by creating a
      new frame which will use Medium Ghosts.
   */
   private class MediumListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         try{
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("PLAY KARELMAN -- MEDIUM");
            frame.setSize(708, 738);
            frame.setLocation(350, 0);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);      
            frame.setVisible(true);
         //create panel for Medium Level within frame      
            MediumPanel medium = new MediumPanel();
            frame.setContentPane(medium);
         }
         catch(IOException i){
         }
      }
   }
   /*
      HardListener is attached to the Hard Button
      It will open the Hard Level by creating a
      new frame which will use Hard Ghosts.
   */
   private class HardListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         try{
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("PLAY KARELMAN -- HARD");
            frame.setSize(708, 738);
            frame.setLocation(350, 0);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);      
            frame.setVisible(true);
         //create panel for Hard Level within frame      
            HardPanel hard = new HardPanel();
            frame.setContentPane(hard);
         }
         catch(IOException i){
         }
      }
   }
   /*
      QuitListener is attached to the Quit Button
      It will make a system call to exit the program.
   */
   private class QuitListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {

         System.exit(0);      

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I see a `GUIPanel`, but no where is the `GUIPanel` created.  I don't see any code that creates the `JFrame`, or attempts to add the `GUIPanel` to said `JFrame`.  I see a `buffer` getting created, and drawn into, but no where do I see the `buffer` being shown anywhere.  I'd say your first problem is in the code that you did not post, not the code you did post.  Try to learn how to create a [mcve], and you'll probably fix your problem in the process.

Comment: Where are you adding your 'welcome' JPanel to the frame ?

Comment: JFrame playFrame = new JFrame();
  JPanel panel = new JPanel(); playFrame.add(panel)

Comment: I have a Driver file in which i create a GUIPanel object and add it to the frame

Comment: Like most questions like this, call `frame.setVisible(true);` after `frame.setContentPane(hard);`